# change divs opacity in different areas onscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset

I want to achieve something like in the graphic below:
[image]

I just can't make this work with this code.
https://jsfiddle.net/3vy66a7o/

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  $('.object').each(function() {
   var offset = $(this).offset().top;
   var height = $(this).outerHeight();
   offset = offset + height / 2;

   if (offset < 100) {
     $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0);
   } else if ((offset > 200) && (offset < 300)) {
     $(this).css("opacity": "1");
   } else if (offset > 300) {
     $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
   }
 else {
   $(this).css("opacity": "0");
 }
 });
});
```

Comment: attach jquery library in your fiddle

Comment: Not an answer, but you could tidy that code up a lot using a `switch` statement instead of all the `else if`'s. (Personal preference, but I think it would look cleaner)

Comment: still learning jquery so I never heard of switch, but thanks i will take a look at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detect the element position on window and act accordingly.

```
var offset = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/3vy66a7o/3/

Was this the effect you were looking for?

Comment: that's already very close just the smoothness of the effect is missing. Thank you very much